# How to get transformed bytecode of java class?

Tags: java, bytecode

I have an application with several java-agents that are transforming bytecode of my classes in some way. Is there any way to get transformed bytecode of class?

PS. I know how to get source bytecode using Class.getResourceAsStream(). But this is not what I need.

UPDATE.

I have an instrumenter stack that transform my java classes. I have a utility method that should never be called after instrumentation. In the body of this method I am trying to provide diagnostic information. Diagnostic information should contain textual representation of calling method bytecode before and after transformation.

Comment: What did you already try ? Show us some code so we can help

Comment: Yes, there is a way to get the transformed bytecode.  Unfortunately, it's highly unlikely that anybody can tell you *how* based on the scant information that you've provided.

Comment: take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085733/get-java-class-bytecode-from-memoryafter-multiple-transforms

Comment: @Tobías, the answer you are referencing definitely answers my question. So sad that solution it gives requires to cache instrumented bytecode of all transformed classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsURL()` and give it to a `URLClassLoader`. than use the class loader to load your classes.

You'll need to use reflection though.

Comment: This way I'll get class bytecode that was _before_ transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by Transformed byte code...

If you are working with bytecode Aka JVM instruction lists I suggest looking into ASM or BCEL

If BCEL or ASM is too difficult to understand or you simply don't have the time to create your own application to edit bytecode you can use JBE (http://set.ee/jbe/).

Comment: My question is not about how to transform bytecode. I'm sorry for being a bit unclear.